# Where does android camera determine immediate preview frame?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to ensure that the preview frame which is displayed briefly after snapping a picture in Camera corresponds closely to the captured image.  There is a bit of delay between the preview image and the captured image, and when capturing subjects in motion, that's a problem.

In the [Camera code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_camera/blob/master/src/com/android/camera/Camera.java) are these comments:

```
// If postview callback has arrived, the captured image is displayed
// in postview callback. If not, the captured image is displayed in
// raw picture callback.
```

But I don't see it.  I see that at the end of `capture()`, `mPreviewing` is set to false, and the `JpegPictureCallback` resumes previewing after a little bit.  This suggests to me that the frozen image is the one from the moment `mPreviewing` is switched off - I don't see any code that would replace that image with anything fresher.  Are the comments correct?  If so, where is the image updated?